# CSS - Two column form maintaining correct tab order?

Tags: css, forms, semantics

I'm currently building a form to act as an 'edit profile' form. On my design I have the fields split into two columns.

I'm trying to keep the tabbing order correct on my form so if tabbing through, you will go down the left column and then the right column. My problem is I can't get them to line up quite how I want!

Password should be directly to the right of username, Password(again) should be directly to the right of Company etc.

Please see the attached JSFiddle to see where I am up to - http://jsfiddle.net/Dhz6u/

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a negative margin to the right hand side `div`s:

```
margin: -72px 0 72px;
```

You need the positive bottom margin to make sure the `div`s don't overlap.

For the second fieldset you'll need to give it an even bigger negative margin, but if you know the number of divs and can give them a set height it shouldn't matter too much.

See http://jsfiddle.net/chris5marsh/Dhz6u/4/

Answer (score 3):

You must use the 'tabindex' property of the fields.

```
<INPUT tabindex="1" type="text" name="field1">
<INPUT tabindex="2" type="text" name="field2">
<INPUT tabindex="3" type="submit" name="submit">
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry I failed to mention I'm probably not going to be able to have such control over the markup as the form will be dynamically generated.

Comment: With JS you could add the attributes programatically.